# How to install fonts on Windows & MAC using Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, fonts

I am creating a silver light 4 application which shows Hindi text using my custom Unicode font, its working fine when I embedded it in silver light application.

Custom font size is approximately 15 MB after compress in xap, it's too big. So is there any possible way to installed font on client machine using Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not belive there is a way to actually *install* it, unless it is possible in a trusted SL4 Out Of browser app.

What you may want to do is package the font in a separate resource assembly and enable *application library caching* on the silverlight application.

Comment: Thanks, I will try Application Library caching

Answer (score 0):

You can do what was done over here to create a sub-set of your font using Blend SDK to make it much smaller: [How to Create Subset Fonts in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249551/how-to-create-subset-fonts-in-net)