# How to generate custom .otf font subset file?

Tags: javascript, c#, fonts, subset, unicode-range

How to generate custom *.otf* font subset file?

**Use case:**

1. There exists gauge *.otf* font file.
2. There exists specific *Unicode* glyph set (ranges, points).
3. Output is new *.otf* file sufficient for set from point 2.

How do this on .NET or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249551/how-to-create-subset-fonts-in-net#answer-6574407) but instead of saving to **.ttf** save it to **.otf.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with using a package, [fontkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontkit) is powerful/flexible and supports TTF, OTF, WOFF, WOFF2, TTC, and DFONT. You should consider this if you are looking for more complicated edits. Below is an example sourced from their readme.

```js
// npm install fontkit
var fontkit = require('fontkit');

// open a font synchronously
var font = fontkit.openSync('font.ttf');

// layout a string, using default shaping features.
// returns a GlyphRun, describing glyphs and positions.
var run = font.layout('hello world!');

// create a font subset
var subset = font.createSubset();
run.glyphs.forEach(function(glyph) {
  subset.includeGlyph(glyph);
});

let buffer = subset.encode();
```